# Mongodb container fails if have a volume setup and more than one container in workload

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, docker-volume, rancher

I have setup a mongodb workload in Rancher (2.5.8)

I have setup a volume:
[image: volume]

The workload start fine if I have the containers set to scale to 1.  So 1 container will start and all is fine.

However if I set the workload to have 2 or more containers, one container will start fine, but then the others fail to start.

Here is what my workload looks like if I set it to scale to 2.  one container started and running fine, but the second (and third if I have its scale to 3) are failing.
[image]

If I remove the volume, then 2+ containers will all start up fine, but then data is only being stored within each container (and gets lost whenever I redeploy).

But if I have the volume set, then the data does store in the volume (host), but then can only start one container.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions

Jason

Comment: Hi, can you share the logs from the container that is failing? I'd reckon this could shed some light on the `CrashLoopBackOff` issue that you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this community wiki answer to set a baseline and to hopefully show one possible reason that the `mongodb` is failing.

Feel free to edit/expand.

---

As there is a lot of information missing from this question like how it was created, how the `mongodb` was provisioned and there is also lack of logs from the container, the actual issue could be hard to pinpoint.

Assuming that the `Deployment` was created with a following manifest:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  replicas: 1 # THEN SCALE TO 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo  
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongo
        image: mongo
        imagePullPolicy: "Always"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data/db
          name: mongodb
      volumes:
      - name: mongodb
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mongo-pvc
```

The part of the setup where the `Volume` is referenced could be different (for example `hostPath` can be used) but the premise of it was:

- If the `Pods` are physically referencing the same `data/db/mongod` it will go into `CrashLoopBackOff` state.

Following on this topic:

- `$ kubectl get pods`

```sh
NAME                     READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
mongo-5d849bfd8f-8s26t   1/1     Running            0          45m
mongo-5d849bfd8f-l6dzb   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   13         44m
mongo-5d849bfd8f-wgh6m   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   13         44m
```

- `$ kubectl logs mongo-5d849bfd8f-l6dzb`

```sh
<-- REDACTED --> 
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-05T12:43:58.025+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"DBPathInUse: Unable to lock the lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock (Resource temporarily unavailable). Another mongod instance is already running on the /data/db directory"}}
<-- REDACTED -->
```

---

Citing the O`Reilly site on the `mongodb` production setup:

> Specify an alternate directory to use as the data directory; the default is `/data/db/` (or, on Windows, `\data\db\` on the MongoDB binary’s volume). Each mongod process on a machine needs its own data directory, so if you are running three instances of `mongod` on one machine, you’ll need three separate data directories. When `mongod` starts up, it creates a `mongod.lock` file in its data directory, which prevents any other `mongod` process from using that directory. If you attempt to start another MongoDB server using the same data directory, it will give an error:
>
> > ```
> > exception in initAndListen: DBPathInUse: Unable to lock the
> >      lock file: \ data/db/mongod.lock (Resource temporarily unavailable).
> >      Another mongod instance is already running on the 
> >      data/db directory,
> >      \ terminating`
> > ```
>
> -- *[Oreilly.com: Library: View: Mongodb the definitive: Chapter 21](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mongodb-the-definitive/9781491954454/ch21.html)*

---

As an alternative approach you can other means to provision `mongodb` like for example:

- *[Docs.mongodb.com: Kubernetes operator: Master: Tutorial: Deploy replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/kubernetes-operator/master/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/)* (I would check the configuration of `StorageClasses` here)
- *[Bitname.com: Stack: Mongodb: Helm](https://bitnami.com/stack/mongodb/helm)*